# Error from mysql query, trying to join tables

Tags: mysql

Can anyone see why this code is returning an error?

```
    "SELECT
a.widget_id,
c.additional_widget_id
FROM
exp_widgets AS a,
INNER JOIN exp_widget_additional AS c ON a.entry_id = c.additional_entry_id
WHERE
a.template = 3
AND
c.additional_template_id = 3
AND
(a.entry_id = 6 OR c.additional_entry_id = 6)
";
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you'd add the error MySQL is giving you.

Comment: It would probably help if you posted the error message.

Comment: FWIW, that final WHERE clause is tautological. You've stipulated that `a.entry_id = c.additional_entry_id`, so `(a.entry_id = 6 OR c.additional_entry_id = 6)` is the same as `a.entry_id = 6`

Answer (score 3):

You have a rogue comma:

```
...
exp_widgets AS a,
INNER JOIN exp_widget_additional`
...
```

should be

```
...
exp_widgets AS a
INNER JOIN exp_widget_additional
...
```